# Whats wrong with this code used to delete and return the last Link in a Linked List?

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list

```
public Link getEnd(LinkList a, Link current){       

    if(current.next == null){

        Link temp = current; //here I save the Link in a variable before nullifying it
        current = null;

        return temp;
    }
    else{
        getEnd(a , current.next);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using a class for `LinkedList` that was written specifically for the CS course I'm taking so keep that in mind if the syntax isn't the same as what you are used to.
What happens here is that I get a null pointer exception and the last Link in the List is the same, nothing happens to it.

Comment: Don't add tags in title. You already used them under your question.

Comment: If you are getting a NPE then that means you are accessing a method or field on a variable that is null. In your code snippet, this only happens on one reference: "current.next". I presume you need to change your first if statement to "if(current == null)"

Comment: Two comments: it looks like you want to return the value returned by your recursive call, and why do you need the `a` parameter if you never use it (except for the recursive call... which doesn't use it either)?

Comment: @bcsb1001 I use _a_ in other methods later on. That's not whats causing the problem, though.

Comment: You are not saving the value returned...

Comment: @Swailem95 By 'later on', if you mean after calling this method, `getEnd()` doesn't need to know about `a`. If you mean from `getEnd()`, please show your full code.

Comment: @bcsb1001 the full code isn't complete yet. I'm trying to reverse a linked list recursively and i'm trying to do that by getting (and removing) the last element in the original and putting it a new LL then removing and doing that again. I'm sure this is not the most efficient way of solving this question but I wanted to see whether it was possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted `current` is a *local* variable. Changing it does not do anything.

You want to **modify the second last element**, and do a

```
secondlast.next = null;
```

to unlink the last element. Furthermore, Java does not allow you to reference the `current.next` *field*, but only to copy the reference. In C, such code can be written much shorter, but this needs full-blown pointer operations.

So you do need to modify your overall logic to look ahead by one more element. The simplest probably is designing your method as

```
public Link getEnd(LinkedList a, Link previous, Link current) {
    ...
    if (previous != null) previous.next = null;
    ...
    else
    ...
    return getEnd(a, current, current.next);
}
```

However, I would suggest to use a non-recursive implementation.

```
public Link getEnd(LinkedList a) {
    if (a.head == null) return null; // Empty list.
    Link previous = null, current = a.head;
    while(current.next != null) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    // Figure out what to do now yourself. It's easy.
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. I just changed the if the statement to current.next.next == null and changed both currents inside it to current.next. I don't have to use previous. I do however have to solve this recursively because that's what the question is asking. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful. When you list is short, the `current.next.next` hack will yield a null pointer exception. Write your code, so that it works on 0 and 1-element lists, too! That last version I posted is IMHO quite clean and robust (note the `null` guard in place).
Also, if the answer helped, please accept it...

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
current = null;
```

Changes the value of a local variable, not the list structure. It has no effect at all.